Prove $ x+1-x \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{1-d}>d$ if $x>0$ and $d\in(0,1)$
I wish to prove or falsify the following inequality:
$$
x+1-x\cdot \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{1-d}>d,x\in(0,+\infty),d\in(0,1)
$$
I tested many points $(x,d)$ programmatically and it looks like the inequality is satisfied. But I don't know how to prove it.
Thanks for any answers or suggestions.

Does this answer your question? Showing $(1+x)^r<(1+rx)$ (MVT) Writing $r=1-d$ and $y=1/x$, your inequality is $$(1+y)^r<1+ry.$$

@AnneBauval . Another way is to let $f(x,d)=x+1-x(1+1/x)^{1-d}-d$ and observe that $\partial f /\partial d >0$.

@AnneBauval Yes, great solution, thank you very much!

@AnneBauval . NO. I mean $\partial f /\partial d.$

@DanielWainfleet Ok thank you (I think we rather have $\partial f /\partial d<0$, but this is what we need).  However, $\partial f/\partial x>0$ seems easier to justify (or its analogous for $(1+y)^r<1+ry$).
